# Check attribute of a subclass

Tags: java, class

I stumbled across that situation but I don't know how to handle it the right way:

```
class Myclass { }
class MyclassWithAwesomeStuff extends Myclass {
    public boolean awesomeStuff;
}
```

I'm saving the Myclass objects in an arraylist and iterate later through this list:

```
for(Myclass m : list) {
    //here I want to check if awesomeStuff is true, in case it is a MyclasswithAwesomeStuff
}
```

The problem here is: the parent class Myclass doesn't know the awesomeStuff attribute (and it shouldn't because that is a feature that comes only with the derived class). But how can I manage this? The problem is, that the arraylist contains Myclass and MyclassWithAwesomeStuff elements and the foreach loop casts them always to Myclass.

I wonder if this is a design failure?

//EDIT:

Okay, to make my question a little bit more tangible, here more infos. I'm trying to build a small coffee shop:

```
class Coffee { }
class CoffeeMix extends Coffee {
    public boolean shaken;
}
```

I'm saving the coffee items in an array list:

```
ArrayList<Coffee> coffees = new ArrayList<Coffee>();
```

So in this array list exist normal coffee objects and coffee mix objects. Now I want to display all coffee mix objects, that are shaken:

```
for(Coffee c : coffees) {
    //here is the same problem as above
}
```

As I can see from the answers/comments: instanceof seems to be a bad idea, because it screws the idea behind oo up and an interface that both classes implement is a bad idea too, because a normal coffee can not be shaken. So how to handle this?

Comment: Yes, this is a design failure - in _your_ code.

Comment: [Relevant](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=31) if you're going to use `instanceof`.

Comment: This is failure to abstract or as i see it OO amnesia.

Comment: Please see my update in the question..

Comment: @freakout well define an interface with `isShackable()` and `isShaken()` methods, no?

Comment: But this would only work when a coffee object is also shackable. But it is not: Just the mix is shakeable.

Answer (score 2):

Test if `m` is a `MyclassWithAwesomeStuff` with the `instanceof` operator.

```
if (m instanceof MyclassWithAwesomeStuff)
{
    MyclassWithAwesomeStuff mwas = (MyclassWithAwesomeStuff) m;
    // Now you can access "awesomeStuff" with "mwas"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use an interface:

```
interface AwesomeStuffable{

    public boolean isAwesome();

}
```

let your classes implement it:

```
class MyClass implements AwesomeStuffable{

  public boolean isAwesome(){

    //your logic here

  }

}
```

And let your `ArrayList` hold just `AwesomeStuffable` objects.

Answer (score 0):

Just to get yourself unblocked, you can do the following:

```
if (m instanceof MyClassWithAwesomeStuff) {
    if (((MyClassWithAwesomeStuff) m).awesomeStuff) {

    }
}
```

But, using instanceof defeats the purpose of inheritance and it appears to be a design flaw to have a need to check for this flag for only some objects in `list` in your code. If you expand the context, probably something better can be suggested.